# Issue in starting Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I have followed all the steps properly but when I start Ubuntu 21.04 in VirtualBox on Windows 11, this screen appears and it gets stuck or it doesn't go any further. How can I fix this and get it to boot properly?

[image: Image of purple screen with the Ubuntu logo at the bottom in VirtualBox]

This is the link where I followed the steps from -- https://youtu.be/nKxS95KO5bQ

Comment: "all the steps properly" - Can you please [edit] your question to include a link to those steps? Thanks!

Comment: I followed this --
https://youtu.be/nKxS95KO5bQ

Comment: Did you assign enough RAM (> 2GB) to the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, I assigned 3 GB RAM and 35 GB hard disk space

Comment: Did you finish installing Ubuntu, or are you booting from a live ISO?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, I did download the Ubuntu 21.04 ISO file and installed Ubuntu on the virtual box through this ISO file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by uninstalling 21.04 and installing 20.04 version of Ubuntu because 20.04 comes with LTS, and this time I followed a bit different set of installation steps. So, now its working completely fine.
Thank you Archisman and cocomac for asking questions. Appreciate it.

I followed this link -- https://youtu.be/x5MhydijWmc